# How to use unicode inside an xpath string? (UnicodeEncodeError)

Tags: python, unicode, xpath, selenium-rc

I'm using xpath in Selenium RC via the Python api.

I need to click an a element who's text is "Submit »"

Here's the error that I'm getting:

```
In [18]: sel.click(u"xpath=//a[text()='Submit \xbb')]")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)

/Users/me/<ipython console> in <module>()

/Users/me/selenium.py in click(self, locator)
    282         'locator' is an element locator
    283         """
--> 284         self.do_command("click", [locator,])
    285 
    286 

/Users/me/selenium.py in do_command(self, verb, args)
    201         body = u'cmd=' + urllib.quote_plus(unicode(verb).encode('utf-8'))
    202         for i in range(len(args)):
--> 203             body += '&' + unicode(i+1) + '=' + urllib.quote_plus(unicode(args[i]).encode('utf-8'))
    204         if (None != self.sessionId):
    205             body += "&sessionId=" + unicode(self.sessionId)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 28: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> sel.click(u"xpath=//a[text()='Submit \xbb')]")
> ```

**It is possible to write XPath expressions that contain any Unicode characters**.

For example:

`//a[text()='Submit &#xBB;')]`

Comment: Does Python provide a facility to encode Unicode like this? I don't see anything relevant in https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev, The right operand of the `=` comparison in the XPath expression is a string that anyone can specify in Python. Even if Python cannot work with Unicode, which I doubt, one can specify the string in the XPath expression and it is XPath that deals with the Unicode conversion

Comment: Of course, I can write these symbols myself, but that's inconvenient, I'd rather write the characters normally and pass them to a conversion function. I'm asking if Python provides some stock function that would convert `u"»"` into `"&#xBB;"`.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: Ask a regular question (not a comment) in the python tag

Comment: `u` at the beginning of the xpath solved my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to change

```
sel.click(u"xpath=//a[text()='Submit \xbb')]")
```

to

```
sel.click(u"xpath=//a[text()='Submit \xbb')]".encode('utf8'))
```

That's because the error indicates Selenium is trying to encode the Unicode object into a byte string (using the default codec for Python, that is, `'ascii'`) and that's what is failing; by explicitly encoding it yourself first, with what's presumably the right codec (`'utf8'`, the default encoding in XML), you should therefore avoid this problem.

Comment: I tried adding that - it still throws a UnicodeDecodeError. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Does sel_click() expect unicode strings or utf-8 (byte) strings? The dreaded UnicodeEncodeError usually happens when you try to pass in the first when the latter (or some other encoding) is expected.

I can't try it right now, but you could try

```
"xpath=//a[text()='Submit \xc2\xbb')]"
```

instead of your argument (which you get by using `.encode('utf-8')`) on it.

Comment: (Hm, nevermind. I seem to have been typing this while Alex Martelli had posted an answer already...)

Answer (score 0):

Im  using selenium and roboframework
I had this similar issue.
I had an Xpath with a special charecter as below:

```
    xpath=(//a[contains(@href,'Ontkoppel cliënt')])[1]
```

and i had to replace with the ascii code and it worked fine.

```
    xpath=(//a[contains(@href,'Ontkoppel cli\u00EBnt')])[1]
```

Hope the example helps a little...

Comment: I don't know what language this is, but it's not Python. The problem asked is Python-specific.

Comment: Hi Ivan, This question was with respect to  using xpath in Selenium RC via the Python api   so here in the above example i have stated the usage of unicode or special char inside the xpath so that to use them in Selenium RC via Python. :)